# Audio is garbled - alsa-pcm front:2: snd_pcm_status error: Broken Pipe

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, troubleshooting

Running on Fedora 34, all up-to-date. This is a new install as of a couple weeks ago. Computer is relatively new, on a good SSD, plays on Windows fine even with heavy usage, so this shouldn't be a straight hardware limit.

When playing videos on VLC, I've noticed audio will cut out for ~0.1-0.3 seconds at a time, often in bursts. It's a lot worse when more resources are being used, so I'm guessing there's a buffer/bottleneck somewhere.

During every audio cutout, journalctl shows the following:

```
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: alsa-pcm front:2: snd_pcm_status error: Broken pipe
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: (speech-dispatcher-dummy-99) client too slow! rate:256/48000 pos:532364032 status:triggered
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: (speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng-105) client too slow! rate:256/48000 pos:532364032 status:triggered
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: (Firefox-113) client too slow! rate:256/48000 pos:532364032 status:triggered
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: (Firefox-118) client too slow! rate:256/48000 pos:532364032 status:triggered
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire[2679]: (VLC media player (LibVLC 3.0.14)-76) client too slow! rate:256/48000 pos:532364032 status:triggered
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire-pulse[2680]: (speech-dispatcher-dummy-16) client missed 1 wakeups
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire-pulse[2680]: (speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng-19) client missed 1 wakeups
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire-pulse[2680]: (Firefox-24) client missed 1 wakeups
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire-pulse[2680]: (Firefox-28) client missed 1 wakeups
Jun 07 12:29:57 DESKTOP-979J3PP pipewire-pulse[2680]: (VLC media player (LibVLC 3.0.14)-10) client missed 1 wakeups
```

So there's some issue to do with wakeups, and resources, but googling around I've not found any good information, unfortunately. Is there any obvious solution/further things to check out here?